# Request Python GraphQl

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql

I get an error when making a request of this type:

```
{'errors': [{'message': 'Variable "$input" of required type "AccountBindBankCardInput!" was not provided.', 'locations': [{'line': 1, 'column': 24}], 'extensions': {'code': 'BAD_USER_INPUT'}}]}
```

[Payload data on website looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abzqo.png)

My payload looks like:

```py
payload = {"operationName": "CreateBinding",

"input": '{lang: "ru", domainSfx: "ru", templateTag: "desktop/form", returnPath: "https://id.yandex.ru/pay", regionId: 1}',

"query": "mutation CreateBinding($input: AccountBindBankCardInput!) {\n  accountBindBankCard(input: $input) {\n    status\n    url\n    __typename\n  }\n}"}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `$input` values needs to be passed in a `variables` block; see the [graphql.org "Serving over HTTP" page](https://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/#post-request) (this wire format is not part of the GraphQL spec).  Within that, the value of `variables` needs to be a structured JSON object, not a serialized string.

Assuming you're going to serialize `payload` to JSON before sending it over the wire, this should look like:

```py
payload = {
  "operationName": "CreateBinding",
  "variables": {
    "input": {
      "lang": "ru",
      "domainSfx": "ru",
      "templateTag": "desktop/form", 
      "returnPath": "https://id.yandex.ru/pay", 
      "regionId": 1
    },
  },
  "query": """
mutation CreateBinding($input: AccountBindBankCardInput!) {
  accountBindBankCard(input: $input) {
    status
    url
    __typename
  }
}
"""
}
```